# How can I find all folders named .svn in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, search

I can't figure out the new search, it seems like it doesn't work correctly.  I know the folder I am searching contains .svn folder.

Comment: Are you looking for them so you can delete them? If so, you're doing it wrong. Read up on `svn export`

Comment: They are actually orphaned files so export wouldn't help.

Comment: Aha. Sorry if my tone was haughty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `name:~".svn"` if you want to use the Windows Search

Comment: NB: this also helps search for parentheses

Comment: Wow, now that's some useful (poorly documented) utility. I had read MS's guide to advanced searching in Windows7 and I don't remember seeing this at all.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it's maddening; I found it while trying to search for files with parentheses, (thanks to the horrid interaction between the new Live Mesh and Photo Gallery's face tagging).  The tilde seems to basically cause Windows to treat the text as literal.

Answer (score 3):

using the commane line:

```
dir /s /b /ad | findstr "\.svn"
```

keep in mind it will also return sub-folders.

Comment: Close, but I'm pretty sure on back on XP I could just find the folder I wanted.  Did they remove this feature? It seems like Windows 7 removed a lot of good power user features.

Comment: Try dir /s /b /ad | findstr ".svn$"

Comment: I tweaked something I already had plus your input `FOR /F "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ".svn" ^| sort /r') do rd "%d" /S`